# Use React ref to store a class instance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The most common use of React Refs is to store a DOM element. However, the React documentation suggests that refs can be used to [store any immutable](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) value, so I was wondering if anyone has been able to implement an actual instance of a class and assigned it to a ref. E.g.:

```js
// Example class
class MyBlueCar {
  constructor(options) {

  }
  ...
}

// React component
import { MyBlueCar } from "./mybluecar.js";

function StartCar() {
  const startEngineRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const myBlueCar = new MyBlueCar();
    startEngineRef.startEngine = myBlueCar
  }, []);
}
```

However I get a `startEngineRef is not extensible` error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ref, `startEngineRef`, is read only. `startEngineRef.current` is mutable.

```
startEngineRef.current.startEngine = myBlueCar
```

In your case, you may consider

```
const startEngine = React.useMemo(() => new MyBlueCar(), [])
```

if you just want to have a single instance for the whole life cycle of the component.